# open graph working with www.domain.com but not with domain.com

Tags: facebook, facebook-opengraph

I've a problem with my facebook open graph, if the user connect to my site with www.domain.com it works properly, but without "www", if the user try the domain.com, it doesn't work.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution? I'm having the same problem, even with both www.domain.com and domain.com registered on the FB App Dashboard.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried adding `domain.com` to your the Website with *Facebook Login field* in your Facebook application settings? So you'd end up with `www.domain.com, domain.com` in the field.

Comment: I'm having the exact same problem - but having both of those things as acceptable domains does not work.